# iOS App rejected, how to get permission for downloading contents all over the Internet?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, app-store, appstore-approval, download-manager

Apple:
 **- 2.3 LEGAL: INTELLECTUAL PROPERTY - AUDIO/VIDEO DOWNLOADING**

I'm building a video downloader app which basically use *UIWebView* and user can surf the internet and download videos from almost everywhere. *App review team* is asking me to provide a documentary evidence of rights to allow media downloading from third-party sources.

How can I get such document?

Comment: You need to negotiate the rights to download the video with its owner. So you probably won't be able get this document as I doubt anyone will give you permission.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because legally acquiring licenses to distribute and not programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about getting legal documents, not programming or coding.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an app store's policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to US law, for copyright protection no advance copyright notice is required. Hence, to obtain *Documentary evidence*, you would need to obtain written evidence from the owner of the material.

This is neither feasible nor possible as there are hundreds of thousands of video content owners. Also, not many of them will be eager to give you permission to use their content for free.

The very premise of your application seems to encourage piracy and is very unlikely to get approved to Apple.

So your best chance to somehow get your efforts to utility would be reducing the scope of your App to certain websites, permission of whose content you can manage to acquire. Giants like YouTube will not entertain your request, but I am sure that if you try you could get the permission out of a bunch of video hosting websites. Then you can present the *Documentary evidence* of permission from these websites to the reviewer. You would also need to restrict your App to work only on these websites.

Another option would be using this concept in Android!! As you are grabbing your videos from a webview, most of your code should remain the same, and there would be no review hurdles in Play store.